# Code doesn't work after updating chart.js versioning

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this great code working here where I load the data in from an external file called test.csv.
Everything works great until I try to update the chart.js library link.
Can anyone tell me why this code doesn't work with more current versions of chart.js?
I want to update it so that I can install the plugin that lets you show the charts values. Alternatively some code that would facilitate this would work great as well!
Appreciate any help!

````
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Data project</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>MY CHART</h1>
    <h2>This is the subhead for my chart </h2>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="250" style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>


    window.addEventListener('load', setup);

    async function setup() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var dollar = await getData();
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',

        data: {
          labels: dollar.years,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Voter support (%)',
              data: dollar.vals,

              backgroundColor: [
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
              ],
            }]
        },

        options: {
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 8,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },

          responsive: true,
          title: {
            display: false
          },


          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            usePointStyle: true,
            padding: 1,
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 15,

            }
          },

          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              gridlines: {
                display: true,
                color: '#ffffff',
                zeroLineColor: '#ffffff',
              }

            }],

            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: true,
                drawOnChartArea: false
              },
            }],
          }


        }
      });
    }

    async function getData() {
      // const response = await fetch('testdata.csv');
      var response = await fetch('data/test.csv');
      var data = await response.text();
      data = data.replace(/"/g, "");
      var years = [];
      var vals = [];
      var rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);

      rows = rows.slice(0, rows.length - 1);
      rows = rows.filter(row => row.length !== 0)

      rows.forEach(row => {
        var cols = row.split(",");
        years.push(cols[0]);
        vals.push(0 + parseFloat(cols[1]));
      });
      console.log(years, vals);
      return { years, vals };

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Coding Train: Data and APIs Project 1</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>MY CHART</h1>
    <h2>This is the subhead for my chart </h2>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="350" height="250" style="background-color:white;"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    // Data from: https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/
    // Mean from: https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/world-of-change/DecadalTemp

    window.addEventListener('load', setup);

    async function setup() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var dollar = await getData();
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',

        data: {
          labels: dollar.years,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Voter support (%)',
              data: dollar.vals,

              backgroundColor: [
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
                '#134D85',
              ],
            }]
        },

        options: {
          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 8,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },

          responsive: true,
          title: {
            display: false
          },


          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'top',
            usePointStyle: true,
            padding: 1,
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 15,

            }
          },

          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              gridlines: {
                display: true,
                color: '#ffffff',
                zeroLineColor: '#ffffff',
              }

            }],

            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: true,
                drawOnChartArea: false
              },
            }],
          }


        }
      });
    }

    async function getData() {
      // const response = await fetch('testdata.csv');
      var response = await fetch('data/test.csv');
      var data = await response.text();
      data = data.replace(/"/g, "");
      var years = [];
      var vals = [];
      var rows = data.split('\n').slice(1);

      rows = rows.slice(0, rows.length - 1);
      rows = rows.filter(row => row.length !== 0)

      rows.forEach(row => {
        var cols = row.split(",");
        years.push(cols[0]);
        vals.push(0 + parseFloat(cols[1]));
      });
      console.log(years, vals);
      return { years, vals };

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: do you get an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start next time might be a good idea to read the documentation and the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html).

Few things that are at least wrong:

- Link name has changed to lower case so `2.9.4/Chart.js` -> `3.5.0/chart.js`
- Scales have changed from 2 arrays to objects for each scale:

```js
options: {
 scales: {
   x: {
     // config for default x scale
   },
   x2: {
     // config for second x scale
   },
   y: {
     // config for default y scale
   },
 }
}
```

- `title` and `legend` config have been moved to the `plugins` section so `options.title` -> `options.plugins.title` and `options.legend` -> `options.plugins.legend`.

Alternativly you could also just use an older release of the [datalabels plugin](https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/) that has been written for V2

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/1.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply! Some excellent options here and I didn't realize there was migration documentation. I will definitely read that and also give the old plug in a try.